# Error about connecting Substrate blockchains to Polkadot with Cumulus

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I'm trying to connect my custom Substrate blockchains to Polkadot with Cumulus, by following the reference https://substrate.dev/cumulus-workshop/#/, I have successfully install Substrate, Relay Chain Node, and Collator Template.

Then, followed the reference, use the built-in rococo-loca to create my own chain spec file. When I move to the next part Launch Relay Chain, I have met some problems, by following the reference https://substrate.dev/cumulus-workshop/#/2-relay-chain/2-launch, I'm going to start Alice's Node, after the node starts I suppose to see several log messages, but it didn't.

How can I solve this problem, or do I miss something to do? Thanks~

**It supposes to look like this:**

```
polkadot \
  --chain spec.json \
  --tmp \
  --ws-port 9944 \
  --port 30333 \
  --alice
```

**Output:**

```
Local node identity is: 12D3KooWLRPJAA6CrXP14FRJztzCh4JmgtRzKWpiBjL3BtseEfyv
```

**But I get this error:**

```
user1215@ubuntu:~/substrate-node-template/polkadot/target/release$ polkadot \
> chain spec.json \
> tmp \
> ws-port 9944 \
> port 30333 \
> alice

polkadot: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're not familiar with Linux. I recommend you learn some Linux first.

In this case, you should run `./polakadot` instead `polkadot`.

```
./polkadot \
  --chain spec.json \
  --tmp \
  --ws-port 9944 \
  --port 30333 \
  --alice

# or this will work for you

~/substrate-node-template/polkadot/target/release/polkadot \
  --chain spec.json \
  --tmp \
  --ws-port 9944 \
  --port 30333 \
  --alice
```